# Word VBA script behaves differently when launched with "Step-into" or "Run"

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is my first attempt at writing a VBA script for Word (I'm an ex-programmer who's had reasonable, self-taught, success with Excel VBA). I'm using Word 2013 (15.0.4641.1001 64-bit) and VBA 7.1 .142.

I'm trying to perfom a simple task, which is to create a two-column table at the current cursor position (which itself can be inside another table). I want the table to be 100% of the width available  to it, then I want to fix the width of the first column. Essentially, my code does what I want (and for a first attempt, I'm reasonably pleased with it), but it's erratic.

The problems relate to the widths. If I position the cursor and "Step-into" the macro, it normally (90%+ of the time) does what I want. If I "Run" it, it never works correctly.

My code is given below. What it's supposed to do is this:-

1. Create a table 5 rows x 2 columns, that is the full width of wherever it's located.
2. Make the first column a fixed width (to accept a short, fixed-format string)
3. Sequentially number each row and right-justify the text.
4. Split column two into two rows per original row.

The problem is with action "2", the others work ok.

- If the table is full-document width, action "2" in "Step into" seems to always work correctly, however
- When it is "Run", action "2" always fails by making the first column 50% wide.
- If I manually create a 1-row by 2-column table and then "Step into" the macro to create a sub-table in each of its two cells :

  - action "2"  for the first sub-table works correctly, but
  - action "2"  for the second sub-table usually sets the first column to 50% instead of fixed width
  - Sometimes action "2" sets the whole sub-table to be 50% of the width of its parent cell, and sets both its columns to be 50% of its own width

One thing I have noticed is that when it executes, the command

```
     .Columns(1).PreferredWidth = 15
```

seems to take noticably longer than other commands.

As I said, this is my first effort and I don't yet know enough to be aware of whether or not I've overlooked some parameter somewhere.

I'd be really grateful if somebody can explain where I'm going wrong and how it can be fixed.

Cheers

Baz

Here's my code.

```
Sub CreateTable()
AddRows = 5
Set NewTable = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, AddRows, 2)
With NewTable
'Display cell borders
    If .Style <> "Table Grid" Then
        .Style = "Table Grid"
    End If
'Make table 100% wide
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    .PreferredWidth = 100
'Make column 1 narrow
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
    .Columns(1).PreferredWidth = 15
    .AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitFixed)
'Number each row
    For a = 1 To AddRows
        .Cell(a, 1).Range.InsertAfter a & ")"
        .Cell(a, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
    Next a
'Split column 2
    For a = 1 To (AddRows * 2) - 1 Step 2
        .Cell(a, 2).Split NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=1
    Next a
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I'm still learning, I don't yet know enough about Word VBA to fully understand why one method works and the other doesn't, but here's a simplified version of the code that worked.

```
Sub MakeTable()
ActiveDocument.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=5, NumColumns:=2, _
    DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow
Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
Selection.Tables(1).Columns(1).PreferredWidth = CentimetersToPoints(1)
'Number each row
For a = 1 To AddRows
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(a, 1).Range.InsertAfter a & ")"
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(a, 1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight
Next a
'Split column 2
For a = 1 To (AddRows * 2) - 1 Step 2
    Selection.Tables(1).Cell(a, 2).Split NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=1
Next a
End Sub
```

Comment: Great!  I suggest you go ahead and "Aceept" this answer.  And I believe you now have enough rep to engage in chat on SO, which could be helpful for this level of trouble shooting.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure `Option Explicit` is at the top of every module, and code compiles (your experience has prolly already guided you on this).
2. Start temporarily commenting out actions, with the goal of isolating the problem further.  I am curious if `.AutoFitBehavior` is an issue.
3. Insert `DoEvents` to help all those little internal buffers to clear.  When you step through code, Events are Doing all the time; maybe not during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for your response Smandoli. I've tried your suggestions but to no avail. Option explicit is active, removed autofit line and, as it's a short routine, tried DoEvents at every possible place.

One thing I've discovered is that if I put a breakpoint after the command
.Columns(1).PreferredWidth = 15
the table formats correctly.

There's a clearly visible delay while this command is executing. It's as if it's performing millions of iterations of something in the background and this presumably is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Good work.  There must be some kind of race condition, even though VBA is by default synchronous and hardly ever misbehaves.  Maybe you can somehow stage these steps, tweak the ordering?

Comment: Hi again Smandoli
I completely re-wrote my script and it now does what I want. I have however encountered another problem, which I should probably ask as a separate question, but maybe you can help.

Comment: Yes, separate. I'll look for it :-) I thnk you should mark this as Accepted if all is settled here.  wel, I guess my answer didn't apply?  Maybe you should explain what you did, OR...

Comment: ... if your fix was something small, we can close this question as "it was only a typo or something small".

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally closed my comment before I completed it. I intended to ask what you know about the "race conditions" that you mentioned. I'm new here so I'm not sure what to do about your response. Although your suggestions didn't fix the issue I want to give you credit for your suggestions, but not give people the impression that they'll find a solution if they have a similar issue. How do I do that?

Comment: That's kind of you.  You can upvote my answer.  Different from accepting it.  As for explaining race conditions... I was considering a possible explanation for the issue, but that's as far as I can go.  No specifics, sorry.

Comment: Upvoted your response. If I can't find appropriate help, I'll post my other problem with the subject "Userform appears too early" (or something similar) after I've done more research into the issue.
Thanks for your time, it's much appreciated.